# How to remove list of kvp from a list of kvp using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 List's say :

```
List< KVP< string, List< KVP< string, object>>>> MainList = new List< KVP< string, List< KVP, object>>>>();
```

Another list :

```
List< KVP< string, object>> SubList = new List< KVP< string, object>>();
```

The SubList is a part of the MainList's List< KVP< string, object>> section.

How can i remove the items present in MainList which are similar to the items present in SubList (condition: Key matches) using LINQ ?

Comment: That's a lot of nesting data structures. Have you considered building a custom class for this data instead?

Comment: We have a stucture similar to the one given above. We need to remove the similar items from the Main List using Linq. Is is possible. As of now, not tried with a custom class.

Comment: @Raj could you define the so-called **similar item**? an item in your main list is a `KeyValuePair` whose value is a **List of** `KeyValuePair`, while an item of the sublist is just a `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: The value of Main List is a KVP. The type of SubList is also a KVP. There are some items in SubList which matches the Value of MainList with "Keys". Need to remove those matched items from the main list.

Comment: I am able to get the common elements between the 2 lists (Note: Key comparison)  var collection = MainList.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();  
var commonPoints = (from item1 in collection  
                    join item2 in SubList on item1.Key equals (item2.Key)  
                    select item1);  
  
Now how can i remove the common points from the MainList ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to try to figure out what you actually want and maybe this is exactly what you are looking for:

```
var newMainList = MainList.Select(e=> 
                             new KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>>(
                                     e.Key,
                                     e=>e.Value
                                         .Where(x=>!SubList.Any(a=>a.Key==x.Key))
                                         .ToList())).ToList();
```

Comment: nice of raj to give you a rep and mark it as answered (the +1 is mine btw ;))

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite a few ways you could solve this, but [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods should work.

```
[Test]
public void RemoveDuplicates()
{
    // Arrange
    var mainList = new List<string>() { "Bogus", "Bodacious", "Brains" };
    var subList = new List<string>() { "Bogus" };
    // Act
    mainList.RemoveAll(search => subList.Contains(search)); // or if not a list 
    mainList = mainList.Except(subList).ToList(); 
    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(mainList.Any(search => subList.Contains(search)));
 }
```

Comment: If you see my question, the structure of both the collection is different. So i cannot use the Except method. I am able to find the matching items between the 2 lists... but I am stuck in removing the matched items from the MainList. Any idea ??